# Custom name for BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE

Tags: boost, googletest, boost-test

Using googletest you can name your parameterized tests based on the parameters using the last argument in [INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/10b1902d893ea8cc43c69541d70868f91af3646b/googletest/docs/advanced.md#specifying-names-for-value-parameterized-test-parameters).

Now I am using `BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE`, and the tests are currently named _0, ..., _N which makes them hard to distinguish. Is there any way that the boost tests can be named in a similar way to googletests parameterized tests?

Comment: There is no such a feature in Boost.Test 1.72. Feel free to make a feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/boostorg/test/issues) !

Answer (score 0):

You can create a more informative test name manually this way

```
std::string getTestName()
{
    namespace b = boost::unit_test::framework;
    auto testName = b::current_test_case().p_name.get();
    if (testName[0] != '_')
        return testName;

    // data driven tests have names like "_0" or "_1"
    auto parentId = b::current_test_case().p_parent_id;
    auto parentName = b::get(parentId, boost::unit_test::TUT_ANY).p_name.get();
    return parentName + testName;
}

BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE(dataDrivenTest, boost::unit_test::data::make({ 1, 2 }), theValue)
{
    std::cout << getTestName() << std::endl;
    BOOST_TEST(theValue > 0);
}
```

The output of the test now reads

```
dataDrivenTest_0
dataDrivenTest_1
```